# How do I make an if command that changes what the script does for a function activated by 2 different tools trying to update a different leader stat

Tags: scripting, roblox

Basically I am trying to make two tools activate the same function except one tool makes the function update one leader stat while the other tool makes the funtion update a different leader stat

```
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.Give

remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player)
    local plr = Player
    if Activated by Starterpack.Child.Cloud then
    plr.leaderstats.JumpBoost.Value = plr.leaderstats.JumpBoost.Value +10
    or if Activated by Starterpack.Child.Speed then
        plr.leaderstats.Speed.Value = plr.Leaderstats.Speed.Value +10
    end
end)
```

I expected it to allow one tool to activate the same function as the other tool but change a different leader stat

Answer (score 0):

[RemoteEvent.FireServer](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireServer) let you pass any number of args when you invoke it. Have your tools each supply a different identifier, and then you can key off the identifier in [RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnServerEvent).

LocalScript inside Tool 1 - Cloud

```
local remoteGive = game.ReplicatedStorage.Give
local tool = script.Parent
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    remoteGive:FireServer("Cloud")
end
```

LocalScript inside Tool 2 - Speed

```
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.Give
local tool = script.Parent
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    remote:FireServer("Speed")
end)
```

Server Script

```
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.Give

remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, toolId)
    if toolId == "Cloud" then
        Player.leaderstats.JumpBoost.Value = Player.leaderstats.JumpBoost.Value + 10

    elseif toolId == "Speed" then
        Player.leaderstats.Speed.Value = Player.Leaderstats.Speed.Value + 10
    end
end)
```

Comment: Do I make a script in both tools with the stuff you put or do I just add that to the function

Comment: I've updated my answer. A LocalScript inside each tool is one solution. Any LocalScript on the player with a path to the tool can connect to the ToolEquipped signal (https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/event/Tool/Equipped)

Comment: There is a problem what do I do now because It was supposed to activate the function when a click was detected that was how I had it working before but now if I just equip a tool it activates the function I am going to try to fix it but we will see

Comment: Tool.Equipped:Connect(function(mouse) end)

Comment: (https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/Mouse)
Use the mouse object in the connection to listen for mouse.Button1Down events.